# mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given.?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

What is the cause of error in my code and how I can to fix?(i use of codeigniter)

```
$query_hotel_search = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE name LIKE '%$hotel_search%' ORDER BY name asc");
$units = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $query_hotel_search ) ) // Line 27
{
   $units = unserialize( $row[0] );
}
echo json_encode(var_dump($units));
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Warning
>  Message:
>   mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
>   Line Number: 27

Output: `array(0) { } null`

**UPDATE:**

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message:
>   unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 3 bytes
>   Line Number: 29

Output: `bool(false) null`

See my database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IORSM.jpg

```
$query_hotel_search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE name LIKE '%$hotel_search%' ORDER BY name asc");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query_hotel_search)==0){
                return '0';
            }else{
                $units = array();
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $query_hotel_search ) )
                {
                   $units = unserialize( $row->units[0] ); // Line 29
                }
                echo json_encode(var_dump($units));
            }
```

Comment: `$query_hotel_search = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE name LIKE '%$hotel_search%' ORDER BY name asc");`

Comment: Can you put your script? are you using PDO? Custom DB class? or something else?

Comment: Are you sure that function is returning the correct thing? Try doing a `var_dump($query_hotel_search)`.

Comment: well at first, $this->db->query seems to return a DB Object or result-set Object.  mysql_fetch_row requires a mysql_query resource which are different.

Comment: Does your $this->db object has a getRows or similar functionality?

Comment: It seems she is combining mysql calls with PDO here

Comment: please read this: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/138304/#682255 , What is your conclusion?

Comment: read the solution above. it use $query = mysql_query($sql); and not $query = $this->db->query($sql);

Comment: that's right. i have new error in code: `$query_hotel_search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE name LIKE '%$hotel_search%' ORDER BY name asc");
            if($query_hotel_search->num_rows()==0){
                return '0';
            }else...` error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 16`. !!!?

Comment: you cannot use $query_hotel_search->num_rows() since it's from the $this->db object, you have to use: mysql_num_rows($query_hotel_search)

Comment: thanks, that's right. sorry i have new error. is update my post please see it again there is new error.

Comment: 1. change mysql_fetch_row to mysql_fetch_assoc() - and use $row['units'] instead of $row->units[0]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

mysql_fetch_row() takes not the query itself but rather the result from the mysql_query command (which is a resource).

Look at the example at the PHP Documentation (linked at the top) and you will get the functionality of mysql_fetch_row.

Maybe the assignment of $query_hotel_search can clarify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a codeigniter object as mysql resource. Instead you should use object iterator provided by codeigniter to loop through the results.

```
foreach($query_hotel_search->result() as $row)
{
// $row as object
}

foreach($query_hotel_search->result_array() as $row)
{
// $row as array
}
```

For the second part (UPDATE), mysql_fetch_row() return an enumerated array. so you should use:

```
$units = unserialize($row[12]);
```